# How come changing background color via JavaScript overrides any CSS selectors on my object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just a quick question... how is it that if I have the following CSS:

```
li { background:red; }
li:hover { background:blue; }
```

With the following JS (or something similar):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
```

My list elements no longer turn blue when I hover over them? I've tested this both on Chrome and FF. And example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/42bQr/. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because inline styes are more specific, you can override inline styles with the following:

```
li:hover { background:blue !important; }
```

Comment: If you are going to select `li:hover` then it is redundant to select `li[style]:hover`.

Comment: You right, I though it was necessary to add more specificity, I'll remove that.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have applied inline style to your selector which has more specifity.

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42bQr/1/)

```
li:hover { background:blue; !important}
```

If you prefer to use Javascript, then you can use [Element ClassList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList). But it is only supported in major browsers. [Browser Compatibility Matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility). Check out this code

### Javascript

```
var listEls = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function addYellowClass() {
  this.classList.add('bg-yellow');
}

for (var i = 0; i <= listEls.length - 1; i++) {
  listEls[i].onclick = addYellowClass;
}
```

### [JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/irAZERU/1/edit?css,js,output)

Comment: I like this soultion better because it is pure CSS and you get the same effect as adding an overriding class without the javscript/DOM walking overhead.

Comment: -1 for recommending to use !important. [Using !important is bad practice because it makes debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your stylesheets.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: @j08691 I agree with you `!important` is not the best solution. +1 for your -1 :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the style is "inline," which takes priority.

Check out this fiddle here to see what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/9m3qw/

The output of the fiddle is:

`<div class="red-bg" style="background-color: yellow;">hello</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are setting the style as an inline style which is the most [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). So when you click on a list item, the result is effectively:

```
<li style="background-color: yellow;">My List Element 1</li>
```

The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:

- Universal selectors
- Type selectors
- Class selectors
- Attributes selectors
- Pseudo-classes
- ID selectors
- Inline style

To get around this, you could instead assign a class to the list item with:

```
var listEls = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i <= listEls.length - 1; i++) {
    listEls[i].onclick = function () {
        this.className = 'yellow'
    };
}
```

where

```
.yellow {
    background:yellow;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/42bQr/3/)**

Comment: I don't think using className blindly is even a good approach. It will override the earlier classes. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/42bQr/8/

Comment: @blunderboy - There are no other classes being applied. You did see the OP's code right? And even if there were, it would be a simply matter of concatenating the new class. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/42bQr/9/

Comment: No its not just a matter of concatenation. Assume you already have that className in your class then you should existence of that class first before concatenating. Otherwise you might end up having `<li class="yellow yellow yellow ..."></li>`

Comment: I like the approach of adding class and increasing specificity but that should be done elegantly.

Comment: I found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList. It prevents the situation I was talking about. Thought to tell you in case it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

As the others have said the inline style takes priority when you click it. You may want to use a hover/mouseover event to add a class ie `$(this).addClass('blueBG')` with the background of blue that is removed onmouseout if that is the effect you are going for.

Comment: OP is not using jQuery

Comment: You're right blunderboy I missed that but he could still edit the class property as a solution. this.className = this.className + " otherclass"; And on mouse out remove the otherclass.

Comment: Well its not that simple. What if your element has already that className. This way you might end up writing jQuery's addClass implementation :)

Comment: I just found your answer and looked at the fiddle blunder boy and have to admit your pure CSS soultion is appears to me the better one! +1

Answer (score -2):

"background-color" is more specific than "background" thus it takes priority in your final style.  essentially your JavaScript code is overwriting both of  CSS properties because it has more weight.

try using background-color as a property in both the CSS and in the JavaScript.

Comment: No. If anything, setting `background-color` should preserve all other properties set by `background`. In CSS, specificity only applies to selectors, not properties.